# Is there a way to profile a Cloud SQL database to find performance bottlenecks and slow queries?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm thinking of using something like the JET profiler to profile an existing instance. I have not found any tools provided by Google itself to profile a Cloud SQL instance.

Comment: Any reason to not use JET profiler?

Answer (score 0):

The console has some graphs that indicate CPU and I/O activity. For more detailed data, there are a number of flags you can use (see https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/mysql-flags#list-flags) such as log_queries_not_using_indexes, long_query_time, and slow_query_log.

Answer (score 0):

On the Developer Console you can monitor these parameters:

[image]

You can also use third party tools like JET Profiler, dbForge Stduio Profiler, etc with Google Cloud SQL.